# Disable Resharper Extensions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper, visual-studio-extensions

I have installed some resharper plugins and since resharper is not loading anymore into VS2013. (Unable to load package).

Does anyone know how to disable/uninstall resharper packages from outside VS?

Running latest (2016.2) version of R#

Comment: I think this cannot be caused by any extensions, but looks more likely like a broken installation.

Comment: Well, it was working perfectly fine without any extensions, then I thought i would check out 3-4 extensions and when it asked me to restart VS, that's when i started getting errors at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit like cracking a nut with a hammer but you could try removing all traces of Resharper from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains` and `%APPDATA%\JetBrains` and re-install it and then re-add the extensions to see which caused you the problem (would be good to know which one it is so that others don't have the same problem.) It seems that the Resharper installation is following the Microsoft standard of spreading numerous cached versions of the same files all over your hard drive to fill it up, not like back in the old days when it was all in just one location.

Comment: thanks, in the end uninstalling + reinstalling worked as it installed without any existing extensions. ATM not installing any extensions just in case... but if I do find the culprit I sure will post a comment